# Update local packages and hot reload to project

Tags: flutter, dart, hot-reload

Hi I have a local package that I import in a project

Project pubspec.yaml:

```
dependencies:
  my_local_package:
    path: ../my_local_package
```

I have both the my_local_package and project open in 2 tabs in android studio. I want to update the my_local_package and press hot reload and receive the updates.

> Update my_local_package -> Press Hot reload in main_project -> Updates received

How can I do this?

Comment: Did you find out a way? I'm looking for it too

Comment: I have to close and reopen the project.

Answer (score 1):

hot reload need sometimes full reload
https://docs.flutter.dev/development/tools/hot-reload#special-cases

Answer (score 0):

The only way I can archive the behavior is to move the local package into the working project, and modify the package within the same window.